# How do I stop File Explorer from spell checking the search box?

Tags: windows-explorer, spell-check

For the past several months, searching for anything with Windows File Explorer is frustrating because it attempts to spell check the search phrase. If I do any type of multi-word search, Windows will overtype my typing and eliminate spaces and change letters as I type. I can only assume this is some type of spell check. I have turned off spell checking in Windows. How can I stop this search interference?

Comment: Why would windows implement such a thing... seems like a bad idea, unless it auto-completed with actual filenames from your files

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Look for a third-party app you've installed that spell-checks *everything*.

Comment: Check in Settings > Devices > Typing, and check if "Autocorrect misspelled words" is on, either at the top, or down below the Hardware Keyboard section. That said, I tried enabling both, and it did not affect file explorer (in Windows 10), so you probably have something else installed like the other comments suggest

Answer (score 0):

DrMoishe Pippik answered the question but I cannot select it as the answer because it was a comment. I had ProWritingAid installed and File Explorer did not have an option to exempt it from spell check so I had to shut down ProWritingAid.